# How to access array inside array in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Here i got some list of array

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "dragonknight",
    "password": "123",
    "email": "dragon@mail.com",
    "nama_lengkap": "Dragon Knight",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-13T05:50:00.559Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-04-13T05:50:00.559Z",
    "grupId": 1,
    "grup": {
        "id": 1,
        "nama_grup": "fleetime",
        "deskripsi": "Ini deskripsi",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-13T05:53:18.423Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-13T05:53:18.423Z"
    }
},
```

the problem is i want to enter grup array and enter nama_grup in flutter how do i do that. i tried with username and nama_lengkap and data show up correctly. but with grup it shows as null.

home.dart

https://pastebin.com/raw/F3Ha8vKK

Comment: could you clarify your question it's quite hard to under stand? provide what's happening and what you want

Comment: I want to show group name dynamically from an API. and i want to show it in Flutter frontend. tthe problem is when i access an array within an array i got null.

Comment: My home.dart dashboard when i access normal array nama_lengkap and it does works. but when i tried nama_grup it shows as null

https://pastebin.com/raw/F3Ha8vKK

Comment: did you access it like `object['grup']['nama_grup']`?

Comment: yup done that still got null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate `grup` from object then access it. Wait for shared instance loaded then find for user string, if found do the json decode. Here is the working example:

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final Future<SharedPreferences> localStorage = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String nama_grup = '';

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();

    // wait for SharedPreferences instance
    final prefs = await localStorage;

    // find user string from SharedPreferences
    final String? user = prefs.getString('user');

    var userGrup = [];

    if (user != null) {
      // decode json string if found
      var userDecoded = json.decode(user);

      setState(() {
        userGrup.add(userDecoded['grup']);
        nama_grup = userGrup[0]['nama_grup'];
      });
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: It says the method [] was called on null
https://imgur.com/96vAWtd

Comment: full code :
https://github.com/fleetimee/frontend_akm/blob/master/lib/screens/dashboard.dart

Comment: You might need do json decode after finding user String see updated code.